# Error: Cannot find module 'pug'

Tags: node.js, pug, pugjs

Here is my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})


app.listen(3333, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3333!')
})
```

index.pug file:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= Hello
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "@npm-private/pug_with_node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.2"
  }
}
```

When I run my server file then it shows me an error. in fact, I install pug and jade both npm modules:

> Error: Cannot find module 'pug'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at new View (/home/software/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:80:30)
>       at Function.render (/home/software/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/software/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
>       at /home/software/Harsh Patel/pug_with_node/index.js:8:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/software/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/software/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)

Comment: What command did you use to install those two modules?

Comment: Where is package.json? Did you do npm install

Comment: make sure you have `pug` inside tour package.json

Comment: I have pug inside my package.json

Comment: I added package.json file as well

Comment: I used: 1) npm install pug@latest -S (2) npm install jade@latest -S

Comment: @HarshPatel You need to have jade, pug and express all in package.json

Comment: @GopeshSharma Yes I have all in package.json file

Comment: @HarshPatel Check you node modules and confirm pug is there.

Comment: @Ved I checked twice!

Comment: I delete my package.json file & node_modules directory and re install all packages. Then I got correct solution.

Answer (score 24):

Try to add this line

```
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express)
```

before

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

This solved the same problem for me!

Comment: No I can't explain! I did more projects with express & pug, and I didn't have that error anymore. In fact, I didn't use the line app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express) anymore.

Comment: All I needed to do was add `"pug": "^2.0.3` under `dependencies` in `package.json`...

Comment: Life saver! For me this started to occur when compiling the server with webpack (I did `__non_webpack_require__("pug").__express` to preserve Node require

Answer (score 19):

When there is a mismatch of module installation between Global and Local you will encounter this issue even if you have installed it all the modules. I would suggest you to install everything local to the project by including the dependency in the package.json

```
npm install --save express jade pug
```

Comment: But I'm using the same version locally and globally.

Comment: @HarshPatel I would suggest you to remove the "dependencies" from the package.json and re-install using command `npm install --save express jade pug`

Comment: Why would you install both `jade` and `pug`? Isn't `jade` just an older version of `pug`?

Comment: @aboveyou00 My understanding is that Jade had to change its name (to Pug) because of a trademark dispute. I can't see a reason for installing them both.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Upvotted. (I did exclude "jade" from the command line but still...)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest fix is to install `pug` as a development dependency: `npm i -D pug`

Answer (score 5):

put     `app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express)`

before

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
 app.set('view engine', 'pug');`

works for me.

After I tried different methods listed. My understanding based on the [official document](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.engine), express by default uses app.engine() function where the callback function need to follow .__express syntax for 'pug' template specificlly.

Answer (score 3):

Runnig: `npm install express` worked for me

I had been forgotten to install express locally.

Also make sure you installed pug. (Run: `npm i pug`)

---

More explaination:

In my system express works even if i don't install it locally (without `npm install express`). so express couldn't find local pug module, because it was running from somewhere else.

Note that if you have express in your dependencies, it doesn't mean that you installed it. run `npm install` to make sure all of dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 2):

Run following Commands..

```
  1.npm remove pug express

  2.npm install pug express
```

This will solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Install

```
npm i pug
```

Put

```
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express);
```

before

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','pug');
```

Comment: This worked @recherche-shafeeq but please can you explain why it is needed for it to run smoothly? I checked other resources online but their explanations were not clear

Comment: @Ekanem Eno because in order to run pug code you need to first install pug engine just like nodejs is installed as a run time environment for javascript.Please refer to pug docs to understand what pug is https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal in your project install the pug like that:

> npm install --save ejs pug express-handlebars

in app.js express

```
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', 'views');
```

in the package.json should look like this

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling pug fixed this for me:

```sh
yarn remove pug
yarn add pug
```

Thanks to Ron Royston for the hint:   [Error: Cannot find module 'pug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342307/error-cannot-find-module-pug#comment92131119_46441440)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple if you are doing it for Nodejs express framework. You can follow any of the below options

1. If you have installed pug globally like adding -g then install pug once again in your project as local npm install pug
2. if the first option is still not working for you then add the following line in your package.json just after "express": "^4.17.1" in the dependency object.

"pug": "^3.0.0"

For me, the first method worked because if you follow the first method then the second will be automatically done.

Answer (score 0):

See in your package.json that your express and pug dependencies was installed or not
If any of them is not installed then installed them by just using

```sh
npm i express

npm i pug
```

And your problem will remove

Answer (score 0):

first verify the package express and pug and if u are open multi-project on your laptop make sure the the port that u use is not used because I got this bug ad when I change the port number is fix fixed.
`const path = require('path') // you don't need to install it app.set('the folder that contain the pug file',path.join(__dirname,'the folder that contain the pug file'); app.set('view engine','pug')`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both (express and pug) are listed as dependencies in your package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.21.2"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue while doing nodeschool.io workshop. I looked where the workshop's compiler was looking for the module and when I manually checked /users/@yourUser/node_modules/ <-(UNIX Mac environment) it was missing. Installing Pug locally fixed the issue with **npm install pug**. In recent versions of Node is not necessary to add the --save flag. If you want to have the pug module added to your node-modules path just ad the -g flag after your install, example: **npm install pug -g** -g stands for global

Answer (score -1):

Many times, even after doing everything right, the error still occurs just because of a tiny mistake of adding a space after 'pug' i.e.,

`app.set('view engine','pug ')`

Such a thing can easily get overlooked while checking your code. So do this instead.

`app.set('view engine','pug')`

Since I have just started learning about express and pug, I faced this issue and realized my problem.